# Is my thermostat transformer voltage too low?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I measured the voltage at the thermostat Rc to G and Rc to Y terminals, and they read 16.2V and 16.34V respectively.  Shouldn't I be measuring 24V+/-?  I purchased a Nest thermostat and it will not work properly at these unusual voltages.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `C` wire at the thermostat?  You should measure between `R` and `C` for a proper voltage reading.

`Y` connects back to the other side of the transformer through the coil of the contactor, in the condensing unit.  `G` connects back to the other side of the transformer through the coil in the fan relay, in the air handler.  `C` connects directly back to the other side of the transformer.

The only way to get an accurate measurement of the transformer voltage, is to measure between `R` and `C`.